# Decode base 64 into image

Tags: uiimage, base64, swift3

I have a base64 string in an array which I can pull out ok but when I try to decode it, str is full but decodedData is nil ? I am not sure why

```
let str = values[0]["image"] as? String
            let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: str!)
            let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
            let pictureDataLocal = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedImage!, 100)
            self.profileImage.image =  UIImage(data: pictureDataLocal!)
```